# wp_dropdown_categories выпадающий список терминов из кастомной таксономии

Tags: wordpress

Когда пользователь находится в категории нужно вывести ее подкатегории, которые относятся к первой категории(родительской), чтобы подкатегории показывались на всех подкатегориях и главной категории(родительской) одинаково, т.е. весь список подкатегорий.

Как добавить пункт Показать все, т.е. чтобы перекидывало на главную родительскую категорию или вывести главную(родительскую) и переименовать на "Показать все"?

Пробовал сделать активный пункт(selected) но с 'value_field' => 'slug' он не работает((

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее большое спасибо!

```
<?php
$term_slug = get_query_var('term');
$taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
'hierarchical'     => 1,
'name'             => 'specializacyja',
'child_of'         => $term->term_id,
'show_option_none' => 'Выберите специализацию',
'taxonomy'         => 'specializacyja',
'value_field'      => 'slug'
));
?>
<script>
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("specializacyja");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > '' ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
            ?>/specializacyja/"+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Другого решения не нашел, по этому решил так.

```
<?php
$term_slug = get_query_var('term');
$taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
$termParent = ($term->parent == 0) ? $term : get_term($term->parent, $taxonomy);
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'hierarchical'     => 1,
    'name'             => 'specializacyja',
    'child_of'         => $termParent->term_id,
    'show_option_all'  => 'Выберите специализацию',
    'taxonomy'         => 'specializacyja',
    'value_field'      => 'slug'
));
?>
<script>
    $("#specializacyja option[value='0']").val('<?php echo $termParent->slug; ?>');
    $('#specializacyja option[value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"]').prop('selected', true);
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("specializacyja");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home') . "/?" . $taxonomy . "="; ?>" +
                dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в параметры

```
'show_option_all' => 'Показать все'
```

а `show_option_none` уберите.

Результирующий код:

```
$term_slug = get_query_var('term');
$taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
$parent = $term->parent;
if ($parent != 0 ) {
    $parent_slug = get_term_by('id', $parent)->slug;
} else {
    $parent_slug = $term->slug;
}
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'hierarchical'     => 1,
    'name'             => 'specializacyja',
    'child_of'         => $term->term_id,
    'show_option_all' => 'Показать все',
    'taxonomy'         => 'specializacyja',
    'value_field'      => 'slug'
));
?>
<script>
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("specializacyja");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != 0 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home') . "/?" . $taxonomy . "="; ?>" +
                dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        } else {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home') . "/?" . $taxonomy . "=" . $parent_slug; ?>";
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

Comment: У show_option_all value=0, а должно value=roditel-cat, ссылка получается /taxonomy/0/ такая

Comment: у вас и скрипт перекорежен неправильно по сравнению с примером с сайта kama. Я исправил все и проверил - работает

Comment: да, я проверял по категориям WooCommerce, сейчас верну под ваши

Comment: подправил код под вашу таксономию

Comment: и да, что вы понимаете под родительской категорией? на одну выше текущей? или вообще - самую верхнюю?

Comment: домен/таксономия/родительский термин/подтермин/ на родительской все правильно отображается, а на дочерних пустой селект.

Comment: вывод подтерминов решил, добавил $termParent = ($term->parent == 0) ? $term : get_term($term->parent, $taxonomy); и 'child_of' => $termParent->term_id, но selected так и не работает и показать все тоже

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58030/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-makissm).